# Using Socket.io with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, arduino

Javascript:

```
var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , server = require('http').createServer(app)
    , io = require('../../lib/socket.io').listen(server)
    , dgram = require('dgram');

server.listen(5000);

var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
var message = new Buffer("100 101 102");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Server Connected");
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        client.send(message, 0, message.length, 8888, '192.168.1.1')
    });
});
```

Relevant HTML:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    socket = io.connect('/');
    $(window).click(function() {
        sendData(100, 101, 102);
    });
});

function sendData(redVal, greenVal, blueVal) {
    socket.emit('message', redVal + " " + greenVal + " " + blueVal);
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "LEDControl",
    "description": "First attempt at mobile node.js and socket.io arduino control",
    "version": "0.0.1-6",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.x",
        "socket.io": "~0.9.16"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.10.x",
        "npm": "1.3.x"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send udp packets via socket.io to an Arduino with an ethernet shield. I'm running this on Heroku. It works fine on localhost, but it always crashes when I try to run it on Heroku. The problem appears to be with socket.io. Websockets is a new feature to Heroku, so it's hard to find much information on it. I've also tried this on Nodejitsu, and got similar results. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Right now it should just send "100 101 102" whenever I click on the screen. The problem could be with limitations of the Arduino Ethernet Shield, I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Did you enable websockets (*heroku labs:enable websockets -a appname*) for your app?

Comment: Yes, websockets are enabled.